# How do you use sql selected data in where/and clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql code which is working fine, but I wanted to know how can I avoid doing RAW data calculation twice, here's my code

```
SELECT `users`.*, ( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
  COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) * 
  COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(locations.LONG)) +
                              SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
  SIN(RADIANS(locations.lat) )) ) AS distance 
FROM   `users` 
INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `users`.`id` = `addresses`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `addresses`.`zip` = `locations`.`zip` 
WHERE  `type` = 'doctor' 
  AND ( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) *
    COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(locations.LONG)) +
    SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) * SIN(RADIANS(locations.lat) )) ) < 100
  AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT  15 OFFSET 0
```

as you can see I'm using this calculation twice `( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) * COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) * COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(locations.LONG)) + SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) * SIN(RADIANS(locations.lat) )) )` on **AND** and **SELECT** statement.

I've tried having `AND distance < 100` but I got an error saying column dont exist.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `having` clause, and that is the best way to solve this problem:

```
SELECT u.*,
       ( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) * COS(RADIANS(l.lat) ) * 
                     COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(l.LONG)) +
                     SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) * SIN(RADIANS(l.lat))
                    )
       ) AS distance 
FROM `users` u INNER JOIN
     `addresses` a 
     ON u.`id` = a.`user_id` LEFT JOIN
     `locations` l
     ON a.`zip` = l.`zip` 
WHERE `type` = 'doctor' AND u.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
HAVING distance < 100
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT  15 OFFSET 0
```

The reason this is better is because MySQL has the habit of materializing subqueries and CTEs, which can add additional overhead.

Comment: I'd have to betray the first guy since your answer is much simpler and only need to change one word from my query

Answer (score 4):

You can place the computed column(s) in a subquery (specifically a "table expression") where the named column is accessible from.

For example:

```
select *
from ( -- the definition of table expression "x" starts
  SELECT `users`.*, ( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
    COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) * 
    COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(locations.LONG)) +
                              SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
    SIN(RADIANS(locations.lat) )) ) AS distance 
  FROM   `users` 
  INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `users`.`id` = `addresses`.`user_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `addresses`.`zip` = `locations`.`zip` 
) x -- the definition of table expression "x" ends
WHERE `type` = 'doctor' 
  AND distance < 100 -- here we use the "distance" column
  AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT  15 
OFFSET 0
```

In MySQL 8.x you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression), as in:

```
with
x as (
  SELECT `users`.*, ( 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
    COS(RADIANS(locations.lat)) * 
    COS( RADIANS(-75.9122) - RADIANS(locations.LONG)) +
                              SIN(RADIANS(43.9743)) *
    SIN(RADIANS(locations.lat) )) ) AS distance 
  FROM   `users` 
  INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `users`.`id` = `addresses`.`user_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `addresses`.`zip` = `locations`.`zip` 
)
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE  `type` = 'doctor' 
  AND distance < 100
  AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT  15 
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: ah, thanks for pointing that out sir, I was looking for a solution in the wrong box lol, could have easily wrap it in a subquery

Comment: @SymmetricsWeb Yes, it's sometimes confusing. In your query "distance" is visible to the `ORDER BY` clause, but not to the `WHERE` clause. I have wondered about that myself...

Comment: well yes, thats what confuses me, the ```ORDER BY``` using distance is working, but the ```AND``` isn't haha, anyway, thanks for your help, you've saved me hours of work,